# Physical page breaks when using csvsimple and pgfpages

Tags: csvsimple, pgfpages

I would like to print initial account data for individual students and place 8 cards on a physical page. This is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a7, paper=landscape, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}


% Creates a card
\newcommand{\Card}[5]%
{%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{Zugangsdaten}
  \medskip\par
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  Klasse:       & \textbf{#1} \\[.7ex]        
  Name:         & \textbf{#2} \\[.7ex]
  Vorname:      & \textbf{#3} \\[.7ex]
  Benutzername: & \texttt{#4} \\[.7ex] 
  Password:     & \texttt{#5} 
  \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
  \clearpage
}

% Layout of logical pages
\geometry{margin = 13mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Shipping-out configuration
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]


\begin{document}

% Example data
\begin{filecontents*}{accounts.csv}
Klasse,Stufe,Vorname,Nachname,Benutzername,Passwort
5a,5,Vorname01,Name01,test01,pwd01
5a,5,Vorname02,Name02,test02,pwd02
5a,5,Vorname03,Name03,test03,pwd03
5b,5,Vorname04,Name04,test04,pwd04
5b,5,Vorname05,Name05,test05,pwd05
5b,5,Vorname06,Name06,test06,pwd06
5b,5,Vorname07,Name07,test07,pwd07
5c,5,Vorname08,Name08,test08,pwd08
5c,5,Vorname09,Name09,test09,pwd09
5c,5,Vorname10,Name10,test10,pwd10
5c,5,Vorname11,Name11,test11,pwd11
5d,5,Vorname12,Name12,test12,pwd12
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[head to column names = true]{accounts.csv}{}%
  {\Card{\Klasse}{\Nachname}{\Vorname}{\Benutzername}{\Passwort}}

\end{document}
```

However, I need to start a new physical page for each new course (Klasse). In the example above there needs to be a physical page for `5a`, `5b` etc. Please note that there can be more than 8 students per course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot tell `pgfpages` to insert a physical page break. So, I think it would be better to use `minipage`s (placing two of them next to each other) instead.

In order to insert a page break, you can compare the last “Klasse” with the current one. If both are not equal, `\clearpage` is inserted.

You may want to adjust the margins, column gap and positioning of the cards.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Creates a card
\edef\prevKlasse{}
\edef\currKlasse{}
\newcommand{\Card}[5]%
{%
  \xdef\currKlasse{#1}
  \ifx\currKlasse\prevKlasse\else\clearpage\fi
  \begin{minipage}[t][65mm][t]{95mm}
  \begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{Zugangsdaten}
  \medskip\par
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  Klasse:       & \textbf{#1} \\[.7ex]        
  Name:         & \textbf{#2} \\[.7ex]
  Vorname:      & \textbf{#3} \\[.7ex]
  Benutzername: & \texttt{#4} \\[.7ex] 
  Passwort:     & \texttt{#5} 
  \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
  \xdef\prevKlasse{#1}
}

% Layout of logical pages
\geometry{margin = 13mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

% Example data
\begin{filecontents*}{accounts.csv}
Klasse,Stufe,Vorname,Nachname,Benutzername,Passwort
5a,5,Vorname01,Name01,test01,pwd01
5a,5,Vorname02,Name02,test02,pwd02
5a,5,Vorname03,Name03,test03,pwd03
5b,5,Vorname04,Name04,test04,pwd04
5b,5,Vorname05,Name05,test05,pwd05
5b,5,Vorname06,Name06,test06,pwd06
5b,5,Vorname07,Name07,test07,pwd07
5c,5,Vorname08,Name08,test08,pwd08
5c,5,Vorname09,Name09,test09,pwd09
5c,5,Vorname10,Name10,test10,pwd10
5c,5,Vorname11,Name11,test11,pwd11
5d,5,Vorname12,Name12,test12,pwd12
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[head to column names = true]{accounts.csv}{}%
  {\Card{\Klasse}{\Nachname}{\Vorname}{\Benutzername}{\Passwort}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514988/82324) by [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) I came up with the following alternative. It may not be as elegant as the original version. It has the advantage, however, of precisely positioning the logical pages without cumbersome calculations.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a7, paper=landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Creates a card

\edef\prevCourse{}
\edef\currCourse{}
\edef\numStudents{0}

\newcommand{\Card}[5]%
{%
   \xdef\currCourse{#1}
   \ifx\currCourse\prevCourse
     \xdef\numStudents{\intcalcInc{\numStudents}}
   \else
     \multido{}
       {\intcalcMod{\intcalcSub{8}{\intcalcMod{\numStudents}{8}}}{8}}
       {\mbox{}\clearpage}
     \xdef\numStudents{1}
   \fi
   \begin{flushleft}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
   \minisec{Zugangsdaten}
   \medskip
   \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
   Klasse:       & \textbf{#1} \\
   Name:         & \textbf{#2} \\
   Vorname:      & \textbf{#3} \\
   Benutzername: & \texttt{#4} \\
   Passwort:     & \texttt{#5} 
   \end{tabular}
   \end{flushleft}
   \clearpage
   \xdef\prevCourse{#1}
}

% Logical pages
\geometry{margin=13mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Shipping-out configuration
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]


\begin{document}

% Example data
\begin{filecontents*}{accounts.csv}
Klasse,Stufe,Vorname,Nachname,Benutzername,Passwort
5a,5,Vorname01,Name01,test01,pwd01
5a,5,Vorname02,Name02,test02,pwd02
5a,5,Vorname03,Name03,test03,pwd03
5b,5,Vorname04,Name04,test04,pwd04
5b,5,Vorname05,Name05,test05,pwd05
5b,5,Vorname06,Name06,test06,pwd06
5b,5,Vorname07,Name07,test07,pwd07
5c,5,Vorname08,Name08,test08,pwd08
5c,5,Vorname09,Name09,test09,pwd09
5c,5,Vorname10,Name10,test10,pwd10
5c,5,Vorname11,Name11,test11,pwd11
5d,5,Vorname12,Name12,test12,pwd12
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[head to column names = true]{accounts.csv}{}%
  {\Card{\Klasse}{\Nachname}{\Vorname}{\Benutzername}{\Passwort}}

\end{document}
```